# Facebook tab not showing when using HTTPS even though SSL certificate is installed

Tags: facebook

For some reason my application has decided to stop loading page tabs when using HTTPS. I do use SSL certificate on my server, the Facebook canvas page even loads using HTTPS;

https://apps.facebook.com/myflashstore

But the Page tab only loads using HTTP even though for a long time it was working with HTTPS just fine.

http://www.facebook.com/trubeats/app_79482449955

https://www.facebook.com/trubeats/app_79482449955

In the app settings, the `Secure Page Tab URL` is the same as the `Page Tab URL` so there shouldn't be an issue. Anyone have any ideas? Help is much appreciated

Comment: facebook is announced removing the Static FBML Page tab app. You shold remove xfbml codes in your application.

Comment: But it's not a FBML page tab app, it's an iFrame tab. Besides it works without HTTPS so is this really the issue?

Comment: iFrame tab redirect facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php. maybe wrong Secure Page Tab URL in your application settings.

Comment: That's odd, it doesn't redirect for me, just shows a blank page tab. It shouldn't be the wrong `Secure Page Tab URL` because it's exactly the same as the regular `Page Tab URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The `Secure Page Tab URL` was a relative URL, relative to my `Canvas URL` - while it worked fine ever since I made the app, and worked fine for HTTP requests, for some reason the `Secure Page Tab URL` now wanted a full URL. Thanks Facebook for continually changing things...makes life much easier for us!